# Color nth element through CSS

Tags: html, css, arrays

I have an array

```
var arr = [2,5,8,11,14,17,....];
```

Use this array we have to apply css background for li elements

Html:

```
      <ul>
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li> // -->2nd li be green 
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li> // -->5th li be green
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li> // -->8th li green like this
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li>
     <li>testing</li> 
    <li>testing</li>
</ul>
```

I tried

```
ul li:nth-child(2n + 2){

       color: green;
  }
```

Any Help???

Comment: try `:nth-child(3n + 2)` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without javascript

```css
li:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <!-- 2nd li be green -->
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <!-- 5th li be green -->
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <!-- 8th li be green -->
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @JqueryKing - It's not what you asked for, though. You asked for a solution where the rows were to be styled by values from an array.

Comment: @Alohci but my arrays are 3n+2 sequentail order. if it is unordered state your are right

Answer (score 3):

Using JavaScript you could do this.

```js
var arr = [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17];
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].style.color = arr.indexOf(i + 1) > -1 ? 'green' : 'black';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
</ul>
```

---

Or using CSS alone.

```css
li:nth-child(3n - 1) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
  <li>testing</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.forEach` and `$.eq`

```
arr.forEach(function(num){
   $('ul li').eq(num - 1).css('backgroundColor', 'green');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/esL81wz1/)

You could also use this instead of using `eq`

```
 $('ul li:nth-child('+ num + ')').css('backgroundColor', 'green');
```

Also as @Phylogenesis said, you could use

```
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
   background: green;
}
```

Comment: is there any method in css without jquery?

Comment: You can use `.addClass("greenClass")` if don't want to use `.css()`

Comment: @AmitJoki, you should substract instead of adding i.e. use `num-1`, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/esL81wz1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}


li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Using a formula (`an + b`). Description: `a` represents a cycle size, `n` is a counter (starts at 0), and `b` is an offset value.

Here, we specify a background color for all `li` elements whose index is a multiple of 3: